# The search functionality of the Help pages isn't working

Tags: bug, search, help-center

I was trying to locate something in the Help pages, but it seems the search functionality isn't working. [A search for "title"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=title) for instance returns this:

[image]

Comment: On MSE it is also broken so it is a network-wide issue...

Comment: A similar issue for chat search was fixed [yesterday](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/263370/158100). Might still be related to the move to Denver...

Comment: Yeah noticed this before searched for `limit` and came back with nothing which I thought was weird.

Comment: Probably another service that doesn't send alerts when falling

Comment: In Denver, nobody can hear you search help.